# Is there a Ubuntu start up repair?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery

Like the way windows has their start up recovery if something goes wrong you can reinstall windows

Does Ubuntu have this?
I’m asking since I’ve been getting stuck at the loading screen  a few times and its been worrying me a little. 
Thanks for reading and answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system for some reason refuses to boot, you have a few options.

**1) System recovery**

Like Windows, Ubuntu also provides an option to boot into a "safe-mode" - the difference is just that Ubuntu (being Unix-like) provides a command-line-interface, from where manuel repairs can be carried out.

read more: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

**2) Ubuntu live-usb**

If you cannot reach the recovery-mode, you can always use a *ubuntu live-usb to acces your system and once again try to repair the system.

**Note:** I'm aware that the two options shown here don't fix anything by themselves (like Windows), but still, combined with some googling and some log-file investigation they can be quit effective.

Answer (score 0):

Just the way Windows has the mode(facility) to start in recover mode or recover it from recovery media. Ubuntu Linux also has got that option. In the grub screen there will be something like "Advanced options" [image]

Also if you have multiple kernel images you can boot into any of them(just like Windows load last good configuration etc...)

For more details, refer to [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/196520/grub2-101-how-to-access-and-use-your-linux-distributions-boot-loader/). If this solves your problem mark it as answer